# Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^2}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've tried, the limit comparison test with several values and have tried finding some values for the direct comparison test but nothing really concrete has come out of it.

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^2}$$

I don't think the integral test would help, and I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that $x > (\ln x)^2 $ and so

$$ \frac{1}{(\ln x)^2} > \frac{1}{x} $$

for $x>1$. Applying this inequality to your case, you can see that the given numerical series is divergent

Comment: Would we have to prove x > (ln x)^2? I suppose I could take the derivative and show that it's negative and that would suffice.

Comment: it is evident..

Answer (score 3):

One can prove that any sum of the form
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{\ln^n{(k)}}$$
diverges where $n\in\mathbb{R}$. Firstly, it can be proven by induction and [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x}=0$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{R}$. Then by using this fact we must have
$$x^n\lt e^x$$
for all $x\gt x_0$ as $x^n$ is increasing and using the definition of a limit. Taking $x=\ln{(t)}$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we get
$$\ln^n{(t)}\lt t$$
for all $t\gt t_0$ where $t_0=e^{x_0}$. Thus for all $k\ge \lceil t_0\rceil$ we have that
$$\ln^n{(k)}\lt k$$
and hence
$$\frac1{\ln^n{(k)}}\gt \frac1k$$
So the sum
$$\sum_{k=\lceil t_0\rceil}^\infty \frac1{\ln^n{(k)}}\gt\sum_{k=\lceil t_0\rceil}^\infty\frac1k\to\infty$$
Hence
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{\ln^n{(k)}}\gt\sum_{k=\lceil t_0\rceil}^\infty \frac1{\ln^n{(k)}}\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Since for **$n>1, n>\log n$** then: **$n\log{n}>\log^2{n}$** and thus: $$\sum_{n>1}{\frac{1}{\log^2{n}}}\ge\sum_{n>1}{\frac{1}{n\log n}}=\infty$$